# My regex is not matching if a line break is found

Tags: c#, regex

I have a large string separated by line breaks.

**Example:**

> *This is my first sentence and here i will search for the word my*
>
> *This is my second sentence*

Using the code below, if I search for 'my' it will only return the 2 instances of 'my' from the first sentence and not the second.

I wish to display the sentence the phrase is found in - which works fine but its just that it does not search anything after the first line break if found.

**Code;**

```
var regex = new Regex(string.Format("[^.!?;]*({0})[^.?!;]*[.?!;]", userSearchCriteraInHere, RegexOptions.Singleline));
var results = regex.Matches(largeStringInHere);

for (int i = 0; i < results.Count; i++)
{
   searchCriteriaFound.Append((results[i].Value.Trim()));
   searchCriteriaFound.Append(Environment.NewLine);
}
```

Code Edit:

```
string pattern = @".*(" + userSearchCriteraInHere + ")+.*";
            RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline;

            foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(largeStringInHere, pattern, options))
            {
                searchCriteriaFound.Append(m.Value);
            }
```

Comment: Please fix your input example because _as is_ it will not even match one time because none of `[.?!;]` are present.

Comment: `RegexOptions.Singleline` is also included in the parameters of string.Format rather than the `Regex` constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var userSearchCriteraInHere = "my";
var largeStringInHere = @"This is my first sentence and here i will search for the word my.

This is my second sentence.";

var regex = new Regex(string.Format("[^.!?;]*({0})[^.?!;]*[.?!;]", userSearchCriteraInHere), RegexOptions.Singleline);
var results = regex.Matches(largeStringInHere);
Console.WriteLine(results.Count);

var searchCriteriaFound = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < results.Count; i++)
{
  searchCriteriaFound.Append((results[i].Value.Trim()));
  searchCriteriaFound.Append(Environment.NewLine);
}

Console.Write(searchCriteriaFound.ToString());
```

This returns the following output:

```
2
This is my first sentence and here i will search for the word my.
This is my second sentence.
```

I did need to add periods at the end of your sentences, as your regex expects them.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a particular reason not to just search for the word "my" multiple times in the following way:

```
(my)+
```

You can test it over at the following URL on Regex101: https://regex101.com/r/QIHWKf/1

If you want to match the whole sentence that has "my" you can use the following:

```
.*(my)+.*
```

https://regex101.com/r/QIHWKf/2

Here your full match is the whole sentence, and your first group match is the "my".

Comment: With the fact that I need to show the sentence the phrase is in - I am not really sure how to go about it. If I use the method above, it returns the word 'my' but I need it to return the sentence it's in.

Comment: @AleksandarZoric That's okay, I edited my answer with a match for the whole sentence that contains "my".

Comment: Please note that `.*(my)+.*` will only return one match if the `SingleLine` option is used, and that it will only return one match _per line_ if it the `SingleLine` option is removed; meaning, if you have more than one instance of `my` in a line, it will match only the last one.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed That's true. Let's see if OP needs all of the "my"s matched and I might give it a try.

Comment: Please see code edit above.  This returns the entire sentence the word 'my' is found in which is great.  Now with my original code - it returned 2-3 words before and after the word 'my' and not the entire sentence. More like the phrase it is in.  Is that possible?

Comment: @AleksandarZoric Well regex engines differ and I'm honestly not particularly familiar with the C# one. Can you try the following maybe `^.*(my)+.*$`

Answer (score 0):

Change

`Regex(string.Format("[^.!?;]*({0})[^.?!;]*[.?!;]", userSearchCriteraInHere, RegexOptions.Singleline)`

To

`Regex(string.Format("[^.!?;]*({0})[^.?!;]*[.?!;]", userSearchCriteraInHere, RegexOptions.Multiline)`

This changes the meaning of the symbols ^ and $ to be at the beginning/end of a line, rather than the entire string.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a word boundary `\b` to prevent it from being part of a larger match like for example `mystery` and change the option to `RegexOptions.Multiline` instead of RegexOptions.Singleline to let `^` and `$` match the end of the line.

`^.*\bmy\b.*$`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BrykdZ/1)

[Test](http://rextester.com/WBEW93471)

Answer (score 0):

To get all lines containing 'my' word, you can try this:

**Code**

```
static string GetSentencesContainMyWord(StreamReader file)
            {
                int counter = 0;
                string line;
                var sb = new StringBuilder();
                while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    if (line.Contains("my"))
                        sb.Append(line + Environment.NewLine);
                    counter++;
                }
                return sb.ToString();
            }
```